# How do I email bcc a list of users from a txt file?

Tags: c#, email

So I am making a program that emails a list of users from a .txt file. Here is what I have so far.

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("testadmin@gmail.com", "MAIL BOT TEST");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("testadmin", "Admin");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

using (StreamReader sr3 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Data\Items\emailItems.txt"))
         {
             string emailList;
             emailList = sr3.ReadToEnd();
             MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress(emailList);
             message.Bcc.Add(bcc);

             Console.WriteLine(emailList);
             MessageBox.Show("" + emailList, "Email List", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
         }
```

The emailList will not work since it throws an exception and it takes:

```
MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("manager1@contoso.com");
```

Below is how the .txt is formatted. Should I seperate them with comments?

```
test01@gmail.com
test02@gmail.com
```

Here is the exception thrown:

```
{"The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."}
```

Thanks and Cheers,
Sean.

Comment: What exception is thrown? What is the format of your text file?

Comment: what does your emailItems.txt look like? is it comma separated?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of the emailItems.txt file, the exact exception name and message and possibly the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailAddress can only take a single address, not a list, so you need to add a MailAddress to Bcc for each recipient.

Assuming your text file has each e-mail address on a line of its own (and your question suggests it has), try this:

```
string[] recipients = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Data\Items\emailItems.txt");

string recipient;

foreach (var recipientLine in recipients)
{
     // Just to take care of leading/trailing spaces and blank lines
     recipient = recipientLine.Trim();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipient))
     {
         MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress(recipient);
         message.Bcc.Add(bcc);   
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 - Exactly the problem. The OP was reading the *whole e-mail list* and passing that as the parameter to the `MailAddress` constructor!

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through the BCC list instead of trying to add at once. You will see if there's a problem, which mail address it is anyway when expention is thrown.